# Parsing NSDictionary returns an empty result.

Tags: ios, json

**I'm using Alamofire to make a request and get data.**

My problem starts after right after json constant, when I'm parsing my dictionaries it gets empty, constant "results" gets empty.

**So my code looks like:**

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                do {
                    guard let data = data else {
                        throw JSONError.NoData
                    }
                    guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary else {
                        throw JSONError.ConversionFailed
                    }

                    if let results = json["results"] as? NSDictionary,
                        let lexicalEntries = results["lexicalEntries"] as? NSDictionary,
                        let entries = lexicalEntries["entries"] as? NSDictionary,
                        let senses = entries["senses"] as? NSDictionary {
                        if let definitions = senses["definitions"] as? String {
                            print(definitions)
                        }
                    }
```

**This is the data model that I need to parse, constant "json" contains this as a dictionary.**

```
{
    metadata =     {
        provider = "Oxford University Press";
    };
    results =     (
                {
            id = hello;
            language = en;
            lexicalEntries =             (
                                {
                    entries =                     (
                                                {
                            etymologies =                             (
                                "early 19th century: variant of earlier hollo; related to holla"
                            );
                            homographNumber = 000;
                            senses =                             (
                                                                {
                                    definitions =                                     (
                                        "used as a greeting or to begin a telephone conversation"
                                    );
```

Comment: Your JSON is not valid, i.e. the semi-colon can't be used in this position, it should be a comma instead.

Comment: @SaschaM78 It's only a piece of my JSON response, I've pasted what I need to reach. The whole response takes like 3 pages.

Comment: can you show what is your response and error?

Comment: There's no error, just nothing goes on. It doesn't print "definitions"

Comment: Even this doesn't print. Is there a special way to treat this dictionary?
if let results = json["results"] as? NSDictionary {
                            print(results)
                        }